# Updating an Entity in EF with a 1:1 relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an application with 4 layers:

```
-Core           (Models)
-Repository     (EF DbContext actions)
-Service        (Business logic)
-Web            (MVC)
```

I'm trying to update an object with a 1:1 relationship with EF using the following method:

```
    public async Task<bool> UpdateProductTicketing(ProductTicketing ticketing)
    {
        var product = await GetProductByIdAsync(ticketing.ProductId);

        // Validation removed for simplicity

        // 'ticketing' passed validation so let's 
        // just replace it with the existing record.
        product.Ticketing = ticketing;


        _repo.ProductRepository.Update(product);
        return await _repo.SaveAsync();
    }
```

This works for an initial insert, but it doesn't work as I'd expect when I'm updating the record:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred...
```

The actual error message is:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.ProductTicketing'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProductTicketing'. The statement has been terminated.
```

Obviously the PK and FK "`ProductId`" doesn't change - so why does EF try to drop and insert my record instead of just updating it, and why does it fail?

But more importantly - how can I prevent this. I know I can manually map the object values and then update it - that works but it's tedious mapping two identical objects together and doesn't feel correct.

My repository for retrieving the `Product` object is in my `Repository` layer, while the method above is in my `Service` layer.

This is how I'm currently resolving this - and it looks as dirty as it feels:

```
    public async Task<bool> UpdateProductTicketing(ProductTicketing ticketing)
    {
        var product = await GetProductByIdAsync(ticketing.ProductId);

        // Validation removed for simplicity

        if (product.Ticketing == null)
        {
            product.Ticketing = ticketing;
        }
        else
        {
            product.Ticketing.AllowEventBooking = ticketing.AllowEventBooking;
            // Doing the same for all other properties etc
            // etc
            // etc
        }

        _repo.ProductRepository.Update(product);
        return await _repo.SaveAsync();
    }
```

How can I achieve this without doing all this horrible mapping an object to an identical object?

### Edit

Here are the two models referred to above:

```
[Table(@"Products")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductTicketing Ticketing { get; set; }
    // Removed others for clarity        

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

[Table(@"ProductTicketing")]
public class ProductTicketing
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public bool AllowEventBooking { get; set; }
    // Removed others for clarity

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

It's also probably worth noting that the "`ProductTicketing`" object I'm passing into the `UpdateProductTicketing` method is a **new** object created from values in my controller - but the ID is the same so I assume it should work.

Comment: Hard to say without looking at your models, but I suspect one of _other_ Ids are changing. Either that or you have not setup navigational properties properly, so EF is not able to track them.

Comment: @Mrchief I've edited the question to include the two models. I'm only using annotations to configure this, not the fluent api. Does this have anything that stands out at you?

Comment: Are you working in connected-mode (context stays alive) or dis-connected mode (context dies and is recreated as needed) ?  Its a big difference.

Comment: HEre is a good tutorial site that pays attention to connected or disconnected mode.......and doesn't always assume one or the other.   http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/update-one-to-one-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I see the problem now - when you do `product.Ticketing = ticketing;`, EF treats this as a new insert.

To avoid this, you can do one of these things:

1. Continue using the workaround (which is not a wokaround actually but just the way EF expects you to tell when to insert vs. when to update).
2. Now this depends on rest of your code and design, but instead of fetching the product, you can fetch the ticket and update its properties. Of course, this means that if the ticketing is not found, you need to insert it which then kinda looks like what you're already doing with `UpdateProductTicketing`.
3. Use the [InsertOrUpdate pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) (I made some assumptions about your code but hopefully it gives you the idea - the main thing here is the `InsertOrUpdate` method):

   ```
   public class ProductRepository : IRepository 
   {    
       private SomeContext context;

       public void InsertOrUpdate(ProductTicketing ticketing) 
       { 
           context.Entry(ticketing).State = ticketing.ProductId == 0 ? 
                                          EntityState.Added : 
                                          EntityState.Modified; 
           context.SaveChanges(); 
       } 
   }


   // And a generic version
   public void InsertOrUpdate<T>(T entity) where T : class
   {
       if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
           context.Set<T>().Add(entity);

       context.SaveChanges(); 
   }
   ```

Comment: The InsertOrUpdate is mentioned here.... as some "backing evidence"  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676

Comment: @granadaCoder: I already have that linked up in my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because ef thinks that the ProductTicket is a new entity and is trying to insert the entity into the db. I don't know about the _repo.ProductRepository.Update(product) call but how about you attach the ProductTicket to the context and set the entity state to modified

Comment: +1 for mentioning to attach the entity to the context.